# Connecting to redis cluster with sentinel on kubernetes

Tags: ruby, redis, kubernetes, redis-sentinel

I've successfully set up a password-protected redis cluster using the guide here:

http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/examples/redis/

I can connect to the sentinel just fine using `redis-cli`, but I cannot connect to the redis master/slave even though I have exposed the sentinels.

I'm using ruby and the following connection string.. Am I doing this wrong?

```
SENTINELS = [{host: "104.122.24.897", port: 26379}]

redis = Redis.new(url: "redis://mymaster", sentinels: SENTINELS, :role => :master, password: "longasspassword", timeout: 16)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error connecting to Redis on 10.64.7.33:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError) (Redis::CannotConnectError)`
```

Comment: What's odd is your error is showing the default port, not the port you specified. Is it not listening to your configuration properly?

Comment: I think sentinels are supposed to just fwd to the redis master right? the port showing up is the redis master port I believe..

Comment: Good point. In that case maybe your sentinel is misconfigured?

Comment: No sentinels do not forward. Think of them as a lookup service. The client has to support sentinel lookups.

Comment: my redis client supports sentinels -- just cannot figure out how to make it use them

Comment: I think the issue is that sentinel is giving a local IP of 10.64.7.33 .. I have tried exposing the redis-master-slave service with a global IP and can connect to it with my password.. but I get the error `(error) READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.` when trying to write something. I can also not connect to master via redis sentinel

Answer (score 1):

I eventually settled on using helm (https://helm.sh/) and installed redis-cluster using `helm install redis-cluster`.

I can connect to the redis cluster using the cluster_ip (not external ip) in kubernetes and this satisfies my security requirement. redis sentinel works out of the box with this approach.